# Symfony ignores fosuser custom roles

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, hierarchy, roles

So, here is my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_CLINICIAN:   ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_CLINICIAN
        ROLE_OWNER:       ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_OWNER

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider:  security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:    true
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_OWNER }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api/clinics, roles: ROLE_CLINICIAN }
```

I should have role hierarchy like this

```
 ROLE_CLINICIAN
       |
   ROLE_ADMIN
       |
   ROLE_OWNER
       |
ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
```

But symfony ignores it, for now i'm want to make ROLE_CLINICIAN be able access only `path: ^/api/clinics` page, but this role still have access to each page

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_CLINICIAN
        ROLE_OWNER:       ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_OWNER

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider:  security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:
                path:   fos_user_security_logout
                target: fos_user_security_login
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/clients, roles: ROLE_CLINICIAN }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_OWNER }
        - { path: ^/#/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

path: ^/ give access to all pages in my app, so the each parent of ROLE_USER have access to each page anyway, but by http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html

`Remember, the first rule that matches is used`, so the trick is to put - { path: ^/#/, roles: ROLE_USER } to the end of list.

Answer (score 0):

Access control rules are evaluated from the top to the bottom. The first matching access control rule wins. In your example, this means that the last four rules will never be considered. And since the `ROLE_CLINICIAN` role includes the `ROLE_USER` role your user will always be granted access.

You can read more about how access control rules are evaluated [in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html).